# Animating Donuts in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am doing a small animation for a teaching course in which I need to draw a donut that moves around following a trajectory. However, I am having a problem with `funcAnimation` insofar as I don't manage to use blit to refresh the position. Here is my code with an example dataset

```
 import numpy as np

 
 x1 = np.random.randint(1,101,10)
 y1 = np.random.randint(1,101,10)
```

The animation itself is done by

```
%matplotlib inline  

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from IPython.display import HTML



fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def make_circle(r,x_c,y_c):
    t = np.arange(0, np.pi * 2.0, 0.01)
    t = t.reshape((len(t), 1))
    x = r * np.cos(t) + x_c
    y = r * np.sin(t) + y_c
    return np.hstack((x, y))

def draw_donut(r_o,r_i,x_c,y_c):
    Path = mpath.Path
    inside_vertices = make_circle(r_i,x_c,y_c)
    outside_vertices = make_circle(r_o,x_c,y_c)
    codes = np.ones(len(inside_vertices), dtype=mpath.Path.code_type) * mpath.Path.LINETO
    codes[0] = mpath.Path.MOVETO
    vertices = np.concatenate((outside_vertices[::1],inside_vertices[::-1]))
    all_codes = np.concatenate((codes, codes))
    path = mpath.Path(vertices, all_codes)
    patch = mpatches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='#885500', edgecolor='black')
    return patch

def animate(i):
    return ax.add_patch(draw_donut(10,5,x1[i],y1[i]))

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = 10, interval=100, blit = False)

ax.set_xlim(-100, 100)
ax.set_ylim(-100, 100)
ax.set_aspect(1.0)

HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```

If I set `blit = True` I get the error

```
TypeError: 'PathPatch' object is not iterable
```

`blit = False` just keep plotting more donuts. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
This includes the full error message, not merely the exception text.
We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.

Comment: Your posted code fails to run: `animation` is undefined.

Comment: I added the definition for animation

Comment: @Prune so now it runs, I checked it. I hope the edits are helpful